# Does the confidence level plus the significance level add to 1?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

From reading it seems to me that the significance level is referred to as $\alpha$ and the confidence level is referred to as $1-\alpha$

However I haven't found statements defining each in terms of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between the confidence level and the significance level for a hypothesis test is as follows:

Confidence level = 1 – Significance level $\alpha$

For example, if your significance level is 0.05, the equivalent confidence level is 95%.
**Reference**: [link](https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/hypothesis-tests-confidence-intervals-levels/)